# How do I set horizontal and vercital borders in python-turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

Borders should look like on the picture. I've tried setting a new picture over it but that's not what it is.
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this?

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()

# Set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])
width,height = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:
    pygame.draw
    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Fill the background with white
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, BLACK, False, [(0,0), (width-1,0), (width-1,height-1), (0, height-1), (0,0)], 3)
    # Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```